# writing to a remote file and converting a string to url

Tags: java, url, applet, uri

I want to write to a remote file as well as read the contents of a remote file. My string is like `http://www.mywebsite.info/other/poll.txt` . How to convert this string into URL/URI ? My goal is to write as well as read the contents of the file hosted on my server. *(via applet)*

Can i use `FileReader` and `FileWriter` for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileReader and FileWriter are used to read and write files from/to the file system.

An applet communicates with its origin server using HTTP. And HTTP isn't a protocol used to read and write files. To read it, you need to open a HttpUrlConnection to this URL. To write it, you'll need to have some server component (a PHP application, a Servlet, whatever) and send an appropriate request to this server component so that it writes to the file.

Read up on how [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) works before trying to write your applet.

Comment: I can't use any class in `java.io.*;` to read write using applets ?

Comment: You'll use classes in IO once you have opened the HTTP connection, because it uses an output stream to send the HTTP request, and an input stream to read the HTTP response. But you won't be able to directly write to a server file through HTTP. That's just not possible.

Comment: Is there a way to write to a file hosted on a server using java.For example when a website opens up applet starts and when the visitor clicks on a button the count is increased by 1 . And this is done by first reading the previous number and then incrementing the number and then writing to that same file

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I explained it in my answer. You must have an application communicating with the applet at server-side.

Comment: @ JB Nizet Can you please tell a way in which i can call  php code (_that will write on file_) from my applet

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for reading -

```
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.mywebsite.info/other/poll.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    url.openStream()));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

              // do something meaningful here when the exception is caught
        } catch (IOException e) {

             // do something meaningful here when the exception is caught
        }
```

Comment: Why ignoring exceptions? Just to make debugging extremely painful?

Comment: I was just giving a quick example...it's not that I am suggesting to ignore exceptions...ok...I put some comments there now...I hope it's clear now.

Comment: by experience, I know that newbies often don't even try to understand the code. They just take it and copy/paste it as is. I find it important to be as scrupulous as possible in answers to avoid bringing an additional problem to the one they already have.